# Webapp hide Android navigation bar (virtual back, homescreen etc. buttons) in Chrome (via javascript)

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, fullscreen

I am making a webapp and would like to create a true fullscreen experience. For Android this includes hiding both the Chrome address bar on top and the navigation bar at the bottom (the virtual back, home and multitask buttons).

I have looked through the [fullscreen api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), [fulscreen experiences article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/) and [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js). All of these implement hiding the Chrome address bar, but not the navigation bar at the bottom. (They do however hide it in some other browsers, like Opera.) I've tested this on Xiaomi mi A2 and Galaxy S8.

There must be a way to achieve this (at least it certainly is for a video element), because fullscreen mode on both YouTube and PornHub are able to hide this menu entirely.

Comment: YouTube auto-hides nav bar because it uses new Chrome's feature of auto-fullscreen in landscape. This works only for `<video>` tags and uses native controls to reveal system UI by swiping top or right side of screen.

Answer (score 11):

Bit late to the party, but hopefully it still helps.

The `requestFullscreen()` method of the Fullscreen API accepts an optional [options object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FullscreenOptions).

```
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen({ navigationUI: 'hide' });
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use a webmanifest.
Put this inside a file:

```
{
   "display": "fullscreen"
}
```

Then add in the head of your HTML:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
```

Check this link for all possible methods:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the fact that fullscreen works as intended when specified in manifest. The problem is that it doesn't work this way in a regular Chrome tab.